# Why do people praise/worship only the tails of cows?

Tags: worship, cows

In many temples, I have seen people praise the tail of a cow instead of its head or legs (*which are common*). Praising the head of a cow is said to be counted as a sin. What is the reason behind this? Is there any mythological story about this practice?

Comment: citation please.

Comment: @VineetMenon I have seen this in many temples.. I didn't read about it anywhere.

Comment: Okay. I thought you could find some..

Comment: I have never come across people praising cow's tail or any other part of cow. Cow as a whole is treated with respect. It is a symbol of purity and holiness (*pavitrata*). I am saying this because I am coming across this for the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Shiva Mahapurana](http://www.godandguru.com/shiv-puran/chapter-10.html) describes an incident when Lord Rama, Sita, and Lakshman heard of the death of King Dashratha. Rama & Lakshmana left to find the required items for the *shraddha* ceremony. When Rama did not return in time, Sita performed them on his behalf.

When Rama returned and Sita told him what she had done, she called on four witnesses: the Falgu river, a Ketaki bush, the fire, and a cow. All denied telling the truth, including the cow. While the cow's mouth lied, the tail, however, shook in agreement with Sita. After Lord Surya appeared and attested to her truth, Sita cursed the four false witnesses: the Falgu river to disappear underground, the Ketaki to never be offered to Lord Shiva, the fire to eat everything indiscriminately, and the cow's mouth to be impure. The hindquarters of the cow remained pure.

Comment: source, http://books.google.co.in/books?id=B4qKuC5_CUwC&pg=PT396&lpg=PT396&dq=Ketaki+bush&source=bl&ots=_Q87H6Iqz_&sig=9BLF7ZjZX5p1PYM2sbYqLGACh5o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9eO7U5v2IsLGuASAkYHQBg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=Ketaki%20bush&f=false

Comment: I can't see the Google books result… on a mobile device. Does it mention specific verses, or a general overview, like in the link I provided? I couldn't find specific verses or chapters.

Comment: it has the exact same story you mentioned.. I didn't read enough to look for verses, though.

Answer (score 0):

The back of the Cow is considered the most auspicious because, as per scriptures Goddess Lakshmi resides there. This is corroborated by Mahabharata also. That is the reason cow dung, urine is also considered very auspicious, not because of other stories. That is reason in all the temples in south India, when the temple doors are open early in the morning, Cow is made to enter with back facing the deity. This is because it is auspicious as Mother goddess Lakshmi resides there and sanctifies all.

Also, Goddess Lakshmi, the consort of Lord Vishnu is auspiciousness of all that is auspicious (She is the ulimate Shiva (auspiciousness)) That is why, in many temples, people praise the tail/back of a cow.

Comment: If this is corroborated by the Mahabharata, then you should include a specific quote from the Mahabharata.

Comment: And during the vishwaroopa dharsan (It is the first dharsan where the temple is opened and public is allowed after this ceremony) the cow is made to stand with the back facing the Lord while the screen is opened for the first time of that day.